# Inset images into plot

Tags: plotting

I have an image (`image1`) in which I am detecting bright objects and showing them in `image2`.

Now I am determining the `number` of objects versus the horizontal position `x` inside of sliding window of dx. The resut (`Transpose[{x,number}]`) is stored in `data`.

I would like to show in a single plot

- `data curve` of number of objects versus x
- `image1` above `image2` above the data curve, *preserving the aspect ratio of the images*

**Question**:

How can I inset (*! from knowing the plot range, size of images, ...* )

- `image1` starting directly from the upper left corner of the plot
- `image2` directly below `image1` (without gap)

In principle it is not necessary to inset the images *into* the plot, but instead somehow to produce a graphics containing in one column from top to bottom `image1`, `image2`, and the `data curve`, whereby the images have the same width as the frame of the plot of data.

What I did:

```
data = << "https://pastebin.com/raw/rgtKLSE9";

image1 = Import["https://i.imgur.com/EGkUvfU.png"];
image2 = Import["https://i.imgur.com/672v5NF.png"];

ylabel = "object number per dx=2.84 mm";

xPixelSize = 0.01420; (* in mm *)

xmax = ImageDimensions[image1][[1]]*xPixelSize;

plot = ListLinePlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
 Epilog -> {Inset[image1, {0, 450}, {0, 0}, Scaled[1]], 
   Inset[image2, {0, 350}, {0, 0}, Scaled[1]]}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{ylabel, ""}, {"x (mm)", ""}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, xmax}, {100, 550}}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 20, 
   FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> 800, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, AxesStyle -> Thick, FrameStyle -> Thick, 
 AspectRatio -> 1.5]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think I'd use inset. I would most likely just display `image1`, `image2` and the plot in a `Column` expression.

Comment: @m_Goldberg: But how can I ensure that the left and right edge of the images fit exactly to the frame of the plotted curve?

Comment: By specifying `ImageSize` for each item in the column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ImageAssemple`  the images and use it in `Inset`:

```
inset = Inset[ImageAssemble[{{image1}, {image2}}], Scaled@{0, 1}, {Left, Top}, Scaled@1];
ListLinePlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, Epilog -> inset,
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{ylabel, ""}, {"x (mm)", ""}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, xmax}, {100, 550}}, ImageSize -> 500, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, AxesStyle -> Thick, FrameStyle -> Thick, AspectRatio -> 1.5]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution is what I was looking for. It works also if image1 and image2 have other sizes.

Comment: @mrz, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
ListLinePlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
Epilog -> {Inset[
GraphicsColumn[{image1, image2}, Spacings -> {0, 
-360*(1. - ImageDimensions[image1][[2]]/ImageDimensions[image1][[1]])}], 
Scaled[{0., 1}], {0, 0}, Scaled[1.1]]}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {{ylabel, ""}, {"x (mm)", ""}}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, xmax}, {100, 550}}, 
BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 20, 
FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> 800, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, AxesStyle -> Thick, FrameStyle -> Thick, 
AspectRatio -> 1.5]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. How did you chose the value -252 in `Spacings -> {0, -252}], ` and the 1.2 in `Scaled[1.2]]}`? Can this somehow be found automatically from the sizes of the images and the `plotRange=PlotRange[plot]`?

Comment: in a hurry, it was by trial-error, but I agree and guess that those values could be found from the images size...

Comment: I think this is what I want to know ... I would like to find an automatic solution.

Comment: Visually, I would prefer a column with image1, image2, and the plot...

Comment: ok, but can you show an automatic finding procedure of the values you found (as you said by trial-error). I mean I also was able to try that out ... but as soon the images size changes the result is not what I want.

Comment: could it be that you scaling of the images in the plot is not proportional to the orginal image? That is a problem.

Comment: Well, 1.1 in `Scaled` comes from the fact that we have to equalise the `AspectRatio` of the `ListPlot` with that of the `Inset`, and -252 in `Spacings` from the removing the empty space left in the square of the standard size of 360x360 surrounding each image. You can resize your images that nothing will change the final inset, except for the scale in the x-axis, I think...